# Are prototypes bad in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, prototype-programming

In [*Felix's Node.js Style Guide*](http://nodeguide.com/style.html) it says:

> Do not extend the prototypes of any
>   objects, especially native ones. There
>   is a special place in hell waiting for
>   you if you don't obey this rule.

[This article](http://howtonode.org/prototypical-inheritance) also made me question the uses of prototypes. If you are going to add a method later on in the code, why not just add it in the original constructor?

So, when is it ever necessary to extend the prototype of an object?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

No, prototypes are not bad.  Quite the opposite, JavaScript is a prototypal language and prototypes are how you are *supposed* to extend objects.

The quote is against extending `Object.prototype` specifically.  Not "An object's prototype".  *Everything* in JavaScript inherits from `Object`, so messing with its prototype effects everything.  It breaks `for(var n in obj){` loops and is just annoying.

That's the only thing against prototypes -- they show up in for-in loops.  Other than that, they are, BY FAR, the best performing way to extend objects in JS.

As for why -- Adding objects in the constructor, say:

```
function myClass(){
    this.someMethod = function(){ ... }
}
```

means you will have a *seperate* function for every instance of the class.  Doing it via a prototype:

```
myClass.prototype.someMethod = function(){ ... }
```

means there will only ever be one copy of that function.  Much more memory efficient, and allows for hot-editing of the language.  Let's say you want to edit String.prototype, for instance:

```
String.prototype.trim = function(){ ... }
```

If you just added that to the constructor somehow, existing strings would not have the `.trim()` method, so the code: `navigator.userAgent.trim()` would not work since `navigator.userAgent` was defined before you added your `trim()` method.

And that article is just Tim being anal and paranoid.  Ignore it :)  As long as you don't forget to type `new myClass()` instead of just `myClass()`, you won't have any issues.

Comment: Ah, thanks a bunch for the awesome explanation. That answered a lot of my questions.

Comment: In your first example using myClass(), you said that it creates a new function for each instance. Does that still apply if instead of using this.someMethod, I used return { someMethod: function(){} }

Comment: @Kevin McTigue - I wrote this like 5 years ago; if you're still confused, let me know: http://www.htmlgoodies.com/primers/jsp/article.php/3600451/Javascript-Basics-Part-8.htm

Answer (score 2):

> Do not extend the prototypes of any
>   objects, especially native ones.

When you extend native objects, like for example string that could be a problem because users are expecting some behavior from that object, but are getting different results. They could get a hard time debugging this..